# Is it possible to move Application JARs libs outside WEB-INF/libs and EAR/lib

Tags: jboss, jboss6.x

We have an EAR with some application specific libs (.jar) in EAR/lib directory. Quite often, during development phase JBoss under Eclipse locks those jars even after undeploy. We must then restart JBoss, loosing time...
Other drawback of embedded jars is remote server deployment upload time, if those jars are big, each deployment requiring uploading those always same JARs.
We have tried several places in jboss directories, all leading to ClassLoader problems at boot phase or run phase of the application.

Note that we have succeed to do this in another external JSF WAR, placing those libs in
    `[JBossInstallDir]/server/default/deployers/jsf.deployers/[OurJSFConfig]/jsf-libs` 
and it works perfectly.

Any idea ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to hot-re-deploy those libs, the .ear file is your best bet.
What you can do during development is to deploy exploded (not as a .zip, but a directory) and only exchange those classes you want changed).
When you then touch myApp.ear/META-INF/application.xml the ear will be re-deployed with changd classes.

When they are static and do not change you can of course put them into e.g jboss/server/default/lib/ folder (for AS4, I think that should work for AS5 as well).

Comment: it is exactly what we do not want to do, meaning redeploy or hot redeploy those libs. They are mainly static third parties utilities libs, that (almost) never change. It is why it is so stupid to package them with the EAR and redeploy them each time. The biggest problem is that JBoss, most of time after an application exception, is write locking those libs (under Windows 7). We do not use application.xml, as we use standard J2EE structure and annotations, in that case application descriptor is not required.

Comment: Heiko, it seems to work as you say for static libs. The point is the libs that we use for the JSF part of our project were conflicting with JBoss jars (like commons-beanutils.jar, commons-logging.jar). We put those in deployers/jsf.deployers/OurConfig/jsf-libs, and there JBoss6 (not 4 or 5) ensure isolation. But regarding the jars we have at the EJB-EAR level they are not existing in JBoss hierarchy. So no class loaders problems, if we put them in server/default/lib.